# Minecraft is blurry

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

When I enter a world for few seconds everything is normal and then it goes blurry. I thought it was something to do with my laptop overheating so I let it cool but that did nothing. I was able to play for few hours normally and then this started. After Googling I found that this might be something called super secret setting, but with that, the GUI would be normal. If I go back to main menu then everything is normal again. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

I'm playing a Minecraft modpack called RLCraft 2.

[image]

Comment: This is a screen, not a desert, things don't get blurry when they are hot. ;)

Comment: if GPU overheats lots of weirdness can start

Comment: "Weirdness" means graphical artifacts like distortion, incorrectly colored pixels, or black screens. I've never seen or heard of an overheating GPU causing things to get blurry.

Comment: "EDIT: This is an issue caused by the ENhanced visuals mod. Removing the mod fixes it." -> question is off-topic as tech support for modded minecraft. The fact that it is already answered does not change its off-topicness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> EDIT: This is an issue caused by the ENhanced visuals mod. Removing the mod fixes it.

(moved from edit by OP to question, where it doesn't belong, to an answer)

Answer (score 7):

You can see in the bottom right corner of your status-bar that you are dehydrated. Shift-Right click a water-source a bunch of times and it should become less blurry.

It's not some error, it's part of the whole dehydration mechanic of the mod-pack.

Comment: No its not. It was actually a bug from enhanced visuals mod. So i removed the mod and issue went away.

Comment: I don't think it's actually a bug from the mod. From what I know from playing RLcraft it's intentional. Have you tried drinking water while it was blurry? @MarkoTaht

Comment: Yes. Didnt work.